# Image fill options on Xamarin buttons, seeing overflow on Android but not iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have some buttons with images in them and we are only seeing the images scale correctly on iOS. On Android the images overflow the button bounds so we get basically a zoomed in version of the image.

```
<Button VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
     <Button.Image>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
             iOS="Revolutions_Button.png"
             Android="Revolutions_Button.png" />
      </Button.Image>
</Button>
```

I have even tried `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest`, and even if that worked, it is not really a viable fix as I do not feel hard coding a height and width makes sense for scaling on different screen sizes. But even these options only resized the button container, the image was still scaled completely differently.

**How do we get the images to scale to fit within the boundary of the buttons on Android?**

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [ImageButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton) control ?

```
<ImageButton VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Aspect="AspectFit"
             Source="Revolutions_Button.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, default Button control in Xamarin Forms doesn't support the your scenario (large image, scaled to fit smaller button, on Android).

Below is how the problem looks like. Image used for the button is bigger than button size (100x50, in this example) and iOS scales image but Android just displays top 100x50 (or 200x100, depending on dpi of the device) pixels from the image.

[image: iOS vs Android preview of the xaml from the question]

**What are your options?**

1. Easiest one would be to [use X-Labs ImageButton control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton). Unfortunately, this project is no longer supported.
2. Extend Button renderer for Android platform that will take care of this problem.
3. Use different images that will not require scale/fit.
4. Create your own Image Button control, examples described [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17402/how-to-create-a-button-with-image) and here

Xamarin.Forms should have Aspect property on the Button to support different strategies for the image rendering, I have created a feature request/bug:

Image control has already this property, see [what are possible values and how they affect image scaling](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Image_and_ImageSource).

I've filed Xamarin bug, feel free to add yourself to mailing list to receive updates: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52938

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm surprised it's so convoluted to do something that seems like it would be an obvious feature... I think for now we'll simply overlay a transparent button on an `Image` object so we can actually scale it etc.

Comment: It is now a confirmed Xamarin.Forms bug and there are workarounds to that (like ImageButton from X-Labs). Hope this helps

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Depending upon the situation Grid layout can be used which will allow adding a transparent button over the image in same grid element.